# Retrofit API call: How to make sure that value is not null after making api call?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, notnull

I have below AuthenticationResponse model that I use for 3 api calls using retrofit2. If I make the verifyEmail call f.e. the JSON response body only contains an attribute for valid email (so something like {"validEmail": true} ). The other 2 calls only contain attributes for "resetSuccesful" or the other 4.

How can I make sure/check that when I receive the response to the verifyEmail call f.e. that it contains a non null value for validEmail??

Service:

```
interface AuthenticationService {

@POST("auth/checkEmail")
fun verifyEmail(@Body email: String): Call<AuthenticationResponse>

@POST("auth/login")
fun login(@Body loginCredentials: LoginCredentials): Call<AuthenticationResponse>

@POST("auth/resetPassword")
fun resetPassword(@Body email: String): Call<AuthenticationResponse>
}
```

Model:

```
data class AuthenticationResponse(

    val validEmail: Boolean? = null,

    val loginSuccess: Boolean? = null,
    val retriesLeft: Int? = null,
    val authToken: String? = null,
    val accountBlocked: Boolean? = null,

    val resetSuccesful: Boolean? = null)
```

---

edit:
If i mock my server response to return f.e. responseCode = 200 - { "validEmail": null } and change validEmail type to Boolean (instead of Boolean?) Retrofit doesn't thrown any kind of exception (this is what i actually want) thus my model is giving me a false negative for my validEmail value..

Comment: Why do you have single `AuthenticationResponse`? It seems to be that it would be more sensible to use separate response model for each API call.

Comment: @miensol: yes, having seperate response models would definitely solve the problem. But I put the question out here because I really wanted to know if there are also a different ways/a way you can make sure certain value is non-null

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely consider @miensol's comment -- to have separate model objects for different API calls.

However, if that's not possible, you can use [`Sealed class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html).

```
sealed class AuthenticationResponse {

    data class EmailValidation(val validEmail: Boolean) : AuthenticationResponse()
    data class SomeSecondResponse(val loginSuccess: Boolean, ...) : AuthenticationResponse()
    data class SomeThirdResponse(val resetSuccessful: Boolean) : AuthenticationResponse()

}

fun handleResponse(response: AuthenticationResponse) {

    when (response) {
        is AuthenticationResponse.EmailValidation -> response.validEmail
        is AuthenticationResponse.SomeSecondResponse -> response.loginSuccess
        is AuthenticationResponse.SomeThirdResponse -> response.resetSuccessful
    }

}
```

`Sealed class` is enums on steroids -- it is enums with states. You have to create 3 classes for 3 responses which inherit from the sealed class `AuthenticationResponse`.

You have to create the specific class instance corresponding to the different API calls. To access the data, you can do type check and access the specific data. The above `when` example shows how to access all the types of response inside a function.

> How can I make sure/check that when I receive the response to the
>   verifyEmail call f.e. that it contains a non null value for
>   validEmail??

Since you create the instance of only the specific classes and all the classes have only non-null properties, you don't have to worry about null.

Comment: I've tried this, but doesn't seem to work as i would want it. If i mock my server response to return  f.e. responseCode = 200 - { "validEmail": null } and change validEmail type to Boolean (instead of Boolean?) Retrofit doesn't thrown any kind of exception thus my model is giving me a false negative for my validEmail value..

Comment: I haven't worked in Retrofit. So I cannot comment on that. The high-level idea is that, for example, for validEmail API call, you have to create an instance of `AuthenticationResponse.EmailValidation` which has `validEmail` as a `Boolean` type. So if you pass null, you will get an exception there.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider what @miensol mentioned in a comment, but if you wanted to add a check for this, you could do something like:

```
fun isEmailValid(authResponse: AuthenticationResponse): Boolean {
    return authResponse.validEmail ?: false
}
```

See Kotlin docs on [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator):

> If the expression to the left of ?: is not null, the elvis operator returns it, otherwise it returns the expression to the right. Note that the right-hand side expression is evaluated only if the left-hand side is null.

Comment: Bob's answer is better than mine and is how you should be doing your response handling in the long run.